# create a new object on image click and use its properties to update the HTML

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a new object when an image is clicked

I am trying the following code (I am pretty unadvanced):

```
<body>
        <h1>Container Verwaltung</h1>
        <p>Welche Containerart wollen Sie anlegen ?</p>
        <div>
            <a href='#' id='gray'>  <img src='gray.png'   width='201' height='423'></a>
            <a href='#' id='yellow'><img src='yellow.png' width='201' height='423'></a>
            <a href='#' id='blue'>  <img src='blue.png'   width='201' height='423'></a>
        </div>

        <p>Liste Ihrer vorhandenen Containers:</p>
        <div id='data'>Containers to be shown</div>

        <script src="containerVerwaltung.js"></script>
    </body>
```

My Javascript looks like this at the moment but I can't get it

```
// function that has to create the new object on button click:
function addContainerBlue(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var containerBlue = new Object();
    containerBlue.name = "blue";
    containerBlue.use  = "paper";
    return containerBlue;
}

// listener for the click:
var blueImageLink = document.getElementById("blue");
blueImageLink.addEventListener("click", addContainerBlue);

// provide info about the object in the HTML:
document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = containerBlue.name;
```

Comment: document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = containerBlue.name; - this line should be inside function, because object isn't created at the page load...

Comment: I actually want to create a new global object with the local function that is called when an image is clicked. I then would like to be able to use the properties of this newly created object outside the function to update the content of elements, but I want that the object remains in the memory after the image click. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the innerHTML inside the click handler, because only there you are creating the object.

```
    // Now this is a global variable
    var containerBlue = new Object();
    function addContainerBlue(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        containerBlue.name = "blue";
        containerBlue.use  = "paper";
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = containerBlue.name;
    }

// listener for the click:
var blueImageLink = document.getElementById("blue");
blueImageLink.addEventListener("click", addContainerBlue);
```

Now when you click on the button the **addContainerBlue** runs, you create the object and set the innerHTML to the name property of the containerBlue.

Comment: I actually want to create a new global object with the local function that is called when an image is clicked. I then would like to be able to use the properties of this newly created object outside the function to update the content of elements, but I want that the object remains in the memory after the image click. Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes just move the containerBlue variable to be outside of the function. I will update the answer.